# Printing streaks on a page

Tags: meaning

> Why is my printer printing the page with streaks?

Does this sentence mean that the printer uses the page that has already streak, in order to prints or the printer makes streaks while printing?

Comment: Here, "page" means "page of the electronic document", not "piece of paper". Printers don't print pieces of paper. They print **on** pieces of paper. What they print is the information.

Answer (score 2):

Let us not be *daft*.  Nobody would use pages with streaks and then wonder why the page has streaks.

So, without even thinking about grammar, the second meaning is the only possible one.

Comment: The point being is that language is about understanding, and we are not robots, so we have some understanding of the wider context, some general knowledge and some common sense.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence:

> (1) Why is my printer printing the page with streaks?

most probably means:

> (1A) Why is my printer causing streaks to appear the paper.

But it could instead mean:

> (1B) Why is my printer printing on the page that already has streaks on it.

(1A) makes more sense in my view, and it fits the words well, so I think it is the most probable meaning.

I can imagine a printer that chooses one of several kinds of paper, from different holders, to print on, but seems to be choosing the wrong one. Then (1B) would make sense. But this requires several assumptions.

Comment: I can't see using the OP's sentence to mean 1B.  The only natural way to phrase that would be "...printing **on** the page with streaks", IMO.